# How to write a reccurence relation for an iterative function

Tags: c++, loops, recursion, iteration, time-complexity

Currently I'm working project which I have to provide an reccurence relation of a function. The thing is that the function is an iterative function and I did not manage to write its reccurence relation. In addition, I am  not sure if such a thing is possible or not. Is there any way to write a reccurence relation for an iterative function.

Here is my code that I struggle with :

```
typedef Pair<Job*>* Schecule;

vector<Schecule>* scheculeJobs(Job* jobs[],int jobCount){
    mergeSort(jobs,0,jobCount - 1 ); // O(nlogn)

    vector<Schecule>* schedules = new vector<Schecule>();

    for (int i = 0; i < jobCount; i++){

        Job* firstJob = jobs[i];

        for(int j = i +1 ; j < jobCount ; j++){

            Job* secondJob = jobs[j];

            Schecule schedule = new Pair<Job*>(firstJob,secondJob);
            schedules->push_back(schedule);
        
            if(schedule->first->deadline == schedule->second->deadline){
                Schecule inverseSchedule = new Pair<Job*> 
                      (secondJob,firstJob);
               schedules->push_back(inverseSchedule);
            }
        }   
    }
    return schedules;
}
```

Comment: pointer on vector is suspicious, you might return directly the vector by value.

Comment: All those `new` are suspicious in fact. (C++ is not Java, no need of `new` everywhere).

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes you may be right.,But The main problem is not that. The function somehow works as expected.

Comment: See [general-way-to-convert-a-loop-while-for-to-recursion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/279004/general-way-to-convert-a-loop-while-for-to-recursion-or-from-a-recursion-to-a)